# Entity Framework 5: Error saving new child entity that has multiple parent relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

For a project at work I have created entities similar to the following:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public Guid ObjectAGUID { get; set; } // key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public Guid ObjectBGUID { get; set; } //key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    public Guid NoteGUID { get; set; } // key
    public Guid AssociationGUID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string NoteType { get; set; }
}
```

Both ObjectA and ObjectB have a 1-Many relationship with Note where Note.AssociatedGUID is the dependent property to A and  B's respective entity key. In other words, A and B can have any number Note entities associate with either one.

**My problem:**

When I create a new ObjectA and a new Note where Note.AssociatedGUID = ObjectA.ObjectAGUID , I get the following error on DBContext.SaveChanges():

```
Entities in 'Entities.Notes' participate in the 'ObjectBNote' relationship. 0 related 'ObjectB' were found. 1 'ObjectB' is expected.
```

**Musings**

If I want to have Notes for both ObjectA and ObjectB do I need to create separate Note entities,say NoteA and NoteB, to do this? If so this seems redundant.

Or, do I need to have a separate nullable foreign key on Note for each parent entity? While more manageable this seems a little overkill as well.

```
public class Note
{
    public System.Guid NoteGUID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid? ObjectAGUID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid? ObjectBGUID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string NoteType { get; set; }
}
```

Help?